# Samba share not in smb.conf

Tags: samba, kde, gui, smb

I'm creating a new File Server for a customer, and decided to load the KDE desktop so that the customer could manage shares and not have to use the CLI.  I set up Samba and shared 3 folders through the smb.conf file, then figured I'd try to share a file from the GUI.  So I right clicked on the folder I wanted to share, and selected the share options and just like that I had an additional shared folder.

I then went back to the SMB.conf file at /etc/samba/smb.conf and wanted to see what "options" sharing through the GUI did to the file, and...  What I expected to see in the smb.conf file was not there, the folder is shared, but it's not shared or configured from the SMB.conf file.  Where are the options set for a shared folder when you create a file share from the GUI?

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 7):

Cite from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide

The shares are defined in the background using the "net usershare" command and the definitions are saved in /var/lib/samba/usershares/ . Therefore, shares defined with this method are not visible in smb.conf.

Comment: Thank you!  So next question.  Is one method favored over the other?  I would like to manage all the shares from one location and thus using the SMB.conf file makes more sense to me.

Comment: Well editing smb.conf is like setting up a proper server compare to sharing folder from KDE is something what is expected to be done on Workstation desktop. Since both are powered by same samba backend, there is no performance difference, but I would slightly favor setting up only via SMB.conf and not using KDE at all on the server.